# Async Controller In HomeController/Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asynchronous

since Index is the default landing zone for a website, is it a good idea to make the home controller an async controller?

In what scenario can I take advantage of AsyncControllers?

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since Index is the default landing zone for a website, is it a good
>   idea to make the home controller an async controller?

No, it isn't a good idea.

> In what scenario can I take advantage of AsyncControllers?

When you have actions that perform intensive I/O tasks and for which you could benefit from I/O Completion ports such as database calls, web service calls, ... I would recommend you reading the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) for better understanding the concept. It's about async ASP.NET pages but async controllers work exactly the same.

Answer (score -1):

You should only use asynch controllers when an operation will take a long time to complete.  Asynch does not magically give better performance, in fact, it will perform *WORSE* than a normal controller.

Asynch controllers, however, allow you to make better use of resources, in particular the thread pool.  Making a controller asynch allows the thread to be returned to the thread pool to service other requests.

If your request doesn't do anything time consuming, then you're just adding overhead for no reason.

Comment: It's not quite true that async controllers allows for threads to be returned to the thread pool to service other requests. This will only be true if the action performs async I/O tasks. If you perform a blocking call there will be no benefit from async controllers and as you said it will worsen things. Async controllers should be used when you are dealing with an API that could benefit from I/O Completion Ports (IOCP).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - True.  But then you're not using it asynchronously.  So it will still add overhead.

Comment: for which case you are talking?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - An Asynch controller, if not used asynchronously will use more resources than a non-asynch controller.  If for no other reason that the `AsyncController` derives from `Controller`, and thus adds overhead.  (this ignores that you could write your own IAsyncController implementation, i'm just talking about using the default classes)